# Will my WCF service be throttled without explicitly setting it via <serviceThrottling>?

Tags: .net, wcf, throttling

Will my WCF service be throttled without explicitly setting it via  ?

Of course, I mean Whilst not specifying it programmatically, either.

By the way, should it matter, I'm asking about WCF 4.0 hosted on IIS 6.0 and the same, hosted on IIS 7.5 - but as far as I can tell, it shouldn't matter for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered by [Wenlong](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/wdong/) in a reply to an email I sent. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/

The answer is **yes**.
Note that the values are larger - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx